# SQL query need to get names where count(id) = 2

Tags: sql

I have a table `programparticipants`. I am currently successfully querying the IDs where `count(name) > 1`. What I need now is to query the names that belong to those IDs where `count(name) > 1`.

Example, data result currently being returned:

```
ID     count(name)
1      2
3      4
4      3
```

Example, data result needed:

```
ID     name
1      nm1
1      nm3
3      nm2
3      nm3
3      nm4
3      nm7
4      nm5
4      nm8
4      nm9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use this:

```
SELECT 
   (SELECT name FROM participants WHERE id=p.participantid) AS name
FROM
   programparticipants AS p
WHERE
   .... (the part where you find count(name)>1)
```

Comment: This was solved by using everyones suggestions and piecing it together

Answer (score 54):

```
select count(id), name 
from programparticipants 
group by name 
having count(id) > 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [GROUP BY and HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_having.asp) are what you want.

Comment: Yep, some combination of group by and having are definitely what he needs.  There's really not enough detail in the question for us to write the entire query.

Comment: I didn't even attempt it.  The link was the best I could come up with quickly.

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, Name 
from programparticipants
where id in ( <your current query selecting only id here> )
```

Comment: '<your current query selecting only ID and not COUNT(*) here>'?

Answer (score 1):

Think you'll want to look at group by with having:

```
select id, name, count(name) from table group by 2,1 having count(name) = 2;
```

You can substitute = 2 for > 1 depending on whatever you want (title says = 2, question says > 1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, Name
FROM   programparticipants
GROUP BY id, Name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```